# Material-UI horizontal menu (mobile friendly)

Tags: css, menu, material-ui

Hi I am trying to create a UI that uses Material-UI but will allow me to move the menu to a collapsible style menu if the user is accessing on a mobile device.

I currently use tabs as at least that is slideable (left and right) But I would like to move away from this and create a menu that is is horizontal but also collapsible into a slide-in the menu if mobile device.

I understand I could use Hidden which would only show it if it is the same width, but I need something a little more smooth - like Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi Russel, what have you done so far ? Could you provide screens or mockups of the wanted behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Material-UI you will probably have to use `Hidden` in order to get the screen's width in px.

In case you want to to a completely different render, you could check out [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect), a library used to detect the type of device the react app is running on. Use the `isMobile` function the library provides and do your rendering accordingly.

A sample code:

```
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';

const myComponent = () => (
    <div>
        {isMobile ?
            // code that will run on phones and tablets
            :
            // code that will run on PCs
        }
    </div>
)

export default myComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding the question correctly but it sounds like what you want is to check the screen size of the user's device and then render the side menu you mentioned above.

Material-ui does have it's grid system which is like Bootstrap and it also has utilities to hide items based on media queries which you can find here https://material-ui.com/system/display/

You can also look into this library which is by react training which allows easy rendering based on media queries https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media

I hope this helps!